# Functions repeats more times than expected Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am doing a python exercise where I need to make an array with x and y. Here are the instructions:

```
"""
Write a program which takes 2 digits, X,Y as input and generates a 2-
dimensional array. The element value in the i-th row and j-th column of the 
array should be i*j.

**Note** : i=0,1.., X-1; j=0,1,¡­Y-1.
**Example**
Suppose the following inputs are given to the program:
3,5
Then, the output of the program should be:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]] 
"""
```

Here is my code:

```
def myfunc(x,y):
    newlist = []
    answer = 0
    icounter = 0
    jcounter = 0
    myarr = []
    for i in range(0, x+1):      
        for j in range(0,y+1):
            answer = jcounter * icounter
            newlist.append(answer)
            jcounter += 1
        jcounter = 0
        icounter += 1
        myarr.append(newlist)
        newlist = []
    print(myarr)

myfunc(3,5)
```

When I run it, my answer is this:

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]]

It should only have 3 lists inside, but it has 4. Does anyone know why?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The range function should be `range(0, x)` and `range(0, y)`

Comment: Remove the `+1`s from the `range()`

Comment: `icounter` and `jcounter` are redundant. just use `i` and `j` instead.

Comment: What's the purpose of the statement `answer = 0`? Your code never uses that value.

Comment: PS. Please tell your teacher that it's confusing to call Python lists arrays. :) Python has several array-like types: there are lists, tuples, and the arrays from the standard `array` module. And then there are Numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your solution, with bug fixes:

```
def myfunc(x, y):
    myarr = []
    for i in range(x):
        row = []
        for j in range(y):
            row.append(i*j)
        myarr.append(row)

    return myarr
```

When invoked as:

```
print(myfunc(3,5))
```

It produces:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

For future reference, a more advanced way to do this is with list comprehensions.  The following is equivalent (and more efficient):

```
def myfunc(x, y):
    return [[i*j for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You end up with range (0,4) which is four elements

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code has four arrays instead of the intended three is because you made the range parameters (0, x+1) instead of just range(x). The following code works fine:

```
my_list = []

def function(x, y):
    for row in range(x):
        my_list.append([])
        for column in range(y):
            my_list[row].append(row * column)


function(3, 5)
print my_list
```

Which outputs the result:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```